# Returning math error (division by 0 etc) that otherwise crashes method

Tags: python

I am working om a simple Python exercise: ask the user for a mathematical formula f(x), which is then evaluated to find the minimum/maximum value of x between x=0 and x=10, with a sample rate of x/100. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
from math import *

def compute_min_and_max():
    Fx = input("what is the desired function of x?" )

    listY = []

    for i in range(0,1001):
        x = i/100
        y = eval(Fx)
        listY.append(y)

    print("This function's minimum value is", min(listY))
    print("This function's maximum value is", max(listY))
```

It works fine, except when the user asks for a formula like log(x), which returns a domain error (for x=0), or 1/(x-a) (which returns a division by 0 error when a=x). How do I, in these cases, return a text string to the user that informs them that there is no min/max value in the interval (or, when as is the case for log(x), there is a maximum value but not a minimum value, how do I print the max value?)

Comment: By using `if` condition.

Comment: Or `try` and `except TheAppropriateError`

Comment: You're not using the values of x anywhere when you `eval(Fx)`. That loop just repeatedly evaluates the function the user typed in without an argument.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I assume the user types in something like 'log(x)', which should work.

Comment: @BilltheLizard `eval` is automatically evaluating x when the user types it in. For example, when the user types in `x+1`, every time it goes through the loop, it computes what `x+1` is and adds it to the list `listY`.

Comment: Do you want to print a specific error message, or would using `try` and `except` (as jonrsharpe suggested) be OK?

Comment: Also: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin

Comment: I hope you are aware that calling `eval` on unvalidated user input is _highly_ dangerous.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Ah, I see. I didn't know `eval` would do that variable substitution for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your statements with an try: except: else: block

```
Fx = input("what is the desired function of x?" )
listY = []

try:
    for i in range(0,1001):
        x = i/100
        y = eval(Fx)
        listY.append(y)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Divide by zero error for f({})".format(x))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid value for f({})".format(x))
else:
    print("This function's minimum value is", min(listY))
    print("This function's maximum value is", max(listY))
```

I'm not sure how you can define there was a min or a max when you have undefined results. You could use limits around the undefined result(s) to understand which direction you approached the undefined value.
But if you want to simply return the min or max of the values that were defined you can move the try block inside the for loop, e.g:

```
Fx = input("what is the desired function of x?" )
listY = []

undefined = False
for i in range(0,1001):
    try:
        x = i/100
        y = eval(Fx)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divide by zero error for f({})".format(x))
        undefined = True
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value for f({})".format(x))
        undefined = True
    else:
        listY.append(y)

if undefined:
    print("Ignoring undefined results")
print("This function's minimum value is", min(listY))
print("This function's maximum value is", max(listY))
```

Comment: Ok, now what about "when as is the case for log(x), there is a maximum value but not a minimum value, how do I print [just] the max value?"

Comment: I'm not sure how you can define there is a minimum or maximum when you have an undefined value. But you can move the try except inside the for loop.

Comment: You probably also want `except ValueError:`, which will catch math module function domain errors, eg `math.sqrt(-1)`, `math.log(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is were python's Exception handling should be used. An example:

```
try:
  foo = 1/0
# catch a specific error
except ZeroDivisionError:
  foo = 0
  print("Division by zero")
# catch all
except Exception as err:
  foo = None
  print("Something really bad happened:", err)
```

In your case, you should wrap the start/end values in a `try: ... except: ...` to catch whether the function is defined at the extremes.

Note that checking whether there is a max/min for arbitrary functions is probably not possible by sampling! Any +/- inf values may be at arbitrary points which you do not sample at all.

Answer (score -1):

Just add an if condition before the for loop and check whether x = 0 or not.
if x = 0 then just print a text string otherwise run your for loop and print the result.

```
from math import *

def compute_min_and_max():
    Fx = input("what is the desired function of x?" )

    listY = []

    for i in range(0,1001):
       x = i/100
       y = eval(Fx)
       listY.append(y)
      if x = 0:
        print('divided by zero')
      else:
        print("This function's minimum value is", min(listY))
        print("This function's maximum value is", max(listY))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if I define my function as `1/(2-x)`

Comment: This also doesn't work if 0 is a valid value, for example, `x-1`.

Comment: And given the test is outside of the for loop, it wouldn't have any effect, an exception would still be raised.